# Creating a path on coordinate system without repeating values (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, coordinate

I'm trying to create a random "path" on a coordinate system on Matlab. I am doing this by creating a for loop where for each iteration it fills in a new value on a matrix that has initial values of zeros.

For example, I have 5 points so I have an initial matrix `a=[0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0]` (row1 = x values, row2 = y values).

The path can move right/left or up/down (no diagonals). In my for loop, I call `randi(4)` and say something like "if `randi(4)`=1, then move 1 point to the left (x-1). if `randi(4)`=2, then move to the right (x+1), etc."

The problem is that  you cannot visit a specific point more than once. For example, the path can start at (0,0), then go to (0,1), then (1,1), then (1,0), and then it CANNOT go back to (0,0).. in my current code I don't have this restriction so I was hoping I could get some suggestions..

Since in this example the matrix would look something like `a=[0 0 1 1 0; 0 1 1 0 0]`.

I was thinking of maybe subtracting each new coordinate (here (0,0)) from each column on the matrix a and if any of the columns give me values of zero for both rows (since it's the same coordinate subtracted from itself), then go back one step and let `randi(4)` run again.. but

1. How could I tell it to "go back one step" (or two or three)?
2. How do you compare one column against each column of the already established matrix?
3. This was just an idea.. are there any functions in Matlab that would let me do this? or maybe compare if two columns are the same within a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

To your questions.

1. to go back - I suppose this means just throwing away the rightmost columns in your matrix.
2. to find if it is present you could use `ismember`

unfortunately it only takes rows so you will need to transpose. Snippet:

```
a = [1:10; repmat(1:2,1,5)]'
test = ismember(a,[3,2],'rows')
any(test) % not found
test = ismember(a,[3,1],'rows')
any(test) % found
```

Of course your idea would also work.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer this:

> How do you compare one column against each column of the already
>   established matrix?

Use two different matrices. Compare them using the setdiff() function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html